# Dismiss “almost time to restart"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, popups, automatic-update, auto-updates

Win 10 seems to love interrupting my movies with update messages I can’t dismiss. Since I’m watching a movie neither restarting now nor waiting an hour is acceptable.

I want to dismiss this thing. I don’t want to teach windows when I’m active. I don’t want to disable updates. I just want the pop up to go away so I can get back to the movie.

If I knew the task name of the pop up I have the keyboard skills to bring up and navigate the task manager (`Alt-space | move` is handy). I just need the name.

Can anyone tell me what task to end to dismiss this thing?

Comment: Prevent the update, rather than the message: set active hours, https://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-active-hours-avoid-windows-10-sudden-restarts-during-updates , or set internet connection to metered, or postpone updates

Comment: @drmoishepippik no. I want to kill the task now. I have a movie to watch.